# Dynamic aws security groups and rules creation(terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, dynamic-programming, terraform-provider-aws, circular-dependency

- I’ve created primary_sg, secondary_sg_tcpci, secondary_sg_tcpqa, secondary_sq_tcpprod security groups.
  primary_sg has three outbound rules to it and each one is associated with secondary_sg securitygroup as destination.
- For secondary, I created three security groups secondary_sg_tcpci, secondary_sg_tcpqa and secondary_sg_tcpprod. Each of these security group inbound rules are associated again with same primary_sg securitygroup as source in it and referring to some local variables.

**main.tf**

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  id = "vpc-1234"
}

data "aws_security_groups" "server_sg"{
  tags = {
    name = "server_sg"
  }
}
locals {
  vpc_id                        = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  server_jumpbox_security_groups = data.aws_security_groups.server_sg.id
}


####### primary_sg###########
resource "aws_security_group" "primary_sg" {
  name        = "primary_security_group"
  description = "Allows outbound rules"
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
} 

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule_01" {
  type                     = "egress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.secondary_sg_tcpci.id       ## Associating secondary_sg_tcpci as destination security group   ####
  description              = "primary_sg rule01"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.primary_sg.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule_02" {
  type                     = "egress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.secondary_sg_tcpqa.id            ## Associating secondary_sg_tcpqa as destination security group   ####
  description              = "primary_sg rule02"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.primary_sg.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule_03" {
  type                     = "egress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.secondary_sg_tcpprod.id          ## Associating secondary_sg_tcpprod as destination security group   ####
  description              = "primary_sg rule02"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.primary_sg.id
}

########secondary_sg#########
resource "aws_security_group" "secondary_sg_tcpci" {
  name        = "secondary_sg_tcpci"
  description = "RDS SG for TCPCI env"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [local.server_jumpbox_security_groups]
    description     = "Server SG"
  }
  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.primary_sg.id}"]
    description     = "Secondary SG"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "secondary_sg_tcpqa" {
  name        = "secondary_sg_tcpqa"
  description = "RDS SG for TCPQA env"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [local.server_jumpbox_security_groups]
    description     = "Server SG"
  }
  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.primary_sg.id}"]
    description     = "Secondary SG"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "secondary_sg_tcpprod" {
  name        = "secondary_sg_tcpprod"
  description = "RDS SG for TCPQA env"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [local.server_jumpbox_security_groups]
    description     = "Server SG"
  }
  ingress {
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.primary_sg.id}"]
    description     = "Secondary SG"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I tried using for_each loop.
**main.tf**

```
 resource "aws_security_group" "secondary_sg_tcpci" {
  for_each =  var.config
  name     = "${each.key}-rds"
  description = "RDS SG for TCPCI env"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.ingress_rules
    iterator = port
    content {
      from_port       = ingress.value.port
      to_port         = ingress.value.port
      protocol        = ingress.value.protocol
      security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.primary_sg.id}"]
    }

  }
 }  
resource "aws_security_group" "primary_sg" {
  
  name        = "primary_security_group"
  description = "Allows outbound rules"
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
} 


resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule_01" {
  type                     = "egress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.secondary_sg_tcpci.id            ## Associating secondary_sg_tcpci as destination security group   ####
  description              = "primary_sg rule01"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.primary_sg.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule_02" {
  type                     = "egress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.secondary_sg_tcpqa.id            ## Associating secondary_sg_tcpqa as destination security group   ####
  description              = "primary_sg rule02"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.primary_sg.id
}
```

**vars.tf**

```
variable "config" {
  description = "Security groups configuration"
  type = map(object({
    name = string
  }))
  default = {
    "sg-1" = {
      name = "sg-1"
    }
    "sg-2" = {
      name = "sg-2"
    }
  }
}
variable "ingress_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    port            = number
    protocol        = string
    
   
    
  }))
  default = {
    "22" = {
      cidr_block      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      port            = 22
      protocol        = "tcp"
      
      
    }
    "22" = {
      cidr_block = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      port       = 22
      protocol   = "tcp"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are attempting here. Do want security group and security group rule creation done dynamically? just the group? just the rules?

Comment: I need both security groups and rules to be in dynamic loop. At the end, I want my code to be minimal without any unnecessary repetitions.

Comment: Do you want to have **both** SGs assigned to the **same** SG rule for SSH? Or you want two **separate** ingress rules for each of the SGs?

Comment: @MarkoE I need separate ingress rules for each SG(primary and secondary).

Comment: Wait, did you create the SGs with or without `for_each`?

Comment: Without ```for_each```

Comment: It's really confusing. Where is the error coming from then if you haven't created the primary SG with `for_each`? It looks like you just posted an error that happened at one point in your testing and reverted back to the code that should be working.

Comment: I tried to create SG using ```for_each``` but as I was mentioning in my question I got **error** and stuck there. Because of error, I never deployed my terraform code using ```for_each```.  Without ```for_each``` I was able create all the resources.

Comment: So you are basically asking someone to write the code for you? :)

Comment: I like when people are honest. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating the SG with `for_each`, you can only access the SG attributes but using proper keys. There is also a small error in other parts of code as in the `dynamic` block you are setting the `iterator` and then later on in the content you are not using it, so you can drop it (as it will default to the dynamic block name which is `ingress`):

```
 resource "aws_security_group" "secondary_sg_tcpci" {
  for_each =  var.config
  name     = "${each.key}-rds"
  description = "RDS SG for TCPCI env"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.ingress_rules 
    content {
      from_port       = ingress.value.port
      to_port         = ingress.value.port
      protocol        = ingress.value.protocol
      security_groups = [aws_security_group.primary_sg.id]
    }
  }
 }

resource "aws_security_group" "primary_sg" {
  name        = "primary_security_group"
  description = "Allows outbound rules"
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "rule_01" {
  for_each                 = aws_security_group.secondary_sg_tcpci
  type                     = "egress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id = each.value.id # <--- this is how you would reference the security IDs for all the SGs created with `for_each`
  description              = "primary_sg rule01"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.primary_sg.id
}
```

This is **only** for the one SG created with `for_each`. This technique is called resource chaining with `for_each` [1]. If you need to repeat the same for other SGs (`tcpqa`, `tcpprod` etc.) you would have to adjust the rest of the code.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources

Comment: Thankyou. I was really struggling to reference IDs for SGs which are created in for_each loop. This part```source_security_group_id = each.value.id``` makes more sense

Comment: Let me know if this works and it does, acceptance would be appreciated.

Comment: This worked, But I've got another question. Can you please go through my  **new question**  which I've edited in my question above.

Comment: Nope, that is a completely new question. Please post that as a new question.